# Trouble Porting Pandas for Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pandas

I have been porting a few things for a computational investing course, and I got all the other macports, but

```
>"sudo port install py27-pandas @0.7.3"
```

is giving me a lot of trouble. This is the return I get:

```
>John--MacBook-Pro:~ John$ sudo port install py27-pandas @0.7.3
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-pandas
--->  Dependencies to be installed: py27-scipy gcc45 swig-python bison gsed swig py27-tables hdf5-18 lzo2 py27-cython cython_select py27-numexpr py27-scientific netcdf
--->  Building gcc45
Error: org.macports.build for port gcc45 returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install gcc45
Please see the log file for port gcc45 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc45/gcc45/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: py27-scipy gcc45 swig-python bison gsed swig py27-tables hdf5-18 lzo2 py27-cython cython_select py27-numexpr py27-scientific netcdf
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port py27-pandas failed
```

I do have Xcode, CLT for Xcode, but I must be missing something else. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: It tells you to look in the log file. Have you tried that? What does it say? You may need to open a support ticket with MacPorts

Comment: another option is to use easy_install... is there a reason to select 0.7.3? Does this refer to the version of pandas? (which is now 0.9.0)

Comment: poorsod - I do not know how to open the log file. Please give me instructions.

Comment: hayden - as far as I can tell, it is referring to python 2.7, but i will try porting with "0.9.0".

Comment: Surely the py27 is referring to 2.7, **0**.7.3 is the pandas version, note [0.9.0 is in macports](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py-pandas/Portfile). Saying that it's weird that the failure is from gcc45...

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend starting with the free EPDFree (does not include pandas, but can be easy_install'd from source) or Anaconda CE (which includes pandas) distributions if you can't get set up with MacPorts.